# pip numexpr installation and spyder kernal issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, numexpr

I booted up Spyder (Python 3.7) and got this warning:

```
C:\ANACONDA3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\_optional.py:138: UserWarning: Pandas requires version '2.7.0' or newer of 'numexpr' (version '2.6.9' currently installed).   warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
```

If I ignore it, I sometimes get the kernal connection erroring (I'll take a screenshot when/if it happens again).

I tried `pip install pandas --upgrade`, hoping it would upgrade `pandas` and all its dependencies (including `numexpr`), but it just removed pandas 1.3.0 without installing pandas 1.3.4

```
Collecting pandas
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/42/977a30bfb4ce937b188e148fcfbae913a9aa6d22ea3d32fef603444eb588/pandas-1.3.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (10.0MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 10.0MB 1.1MB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.17.3; platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64" and python_version < "3.10" in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.21.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pytz>=2017.3 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2019.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.5 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.12.0)
Installing collected packages: pandas
  Found existing installation: pandas 1.3.0
    Uninstalling pandas-1.3.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pandas-1.3.0
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\u03132tk\\appdata\\roaming\\python\\python37\\site-packages\\~andas\\_libs\\algos.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I then did pip install pandas, and it successfully installed pandas 1.3.4:

```
print (pandas.__version__)
1.3.4
```

I thought it was all good, but I started getting the warnings again.  These went away when I did `pip install numexpr --upgrade` followed by `pip install numexpr` as above.  But now my kernal occassionally restarts for no reason.  Is there something I should do to fix this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `conda install` instead of `pip install`